# Nested Options in React-Bootstrap-Typeahead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-bootstrap

Trying to implemented a nested dropdown with the following options:

```
const options = [
  {
    value: 'one',
  },
  {
    value: 'two',
  },
  {
    value: 'three',
    extraOptions: [
      { value: 'three point one' },
      { value: 'three point two' },
    ],
  }
];
```

In my component I have the following:

```
<Typeahead
  multiple
  type='text'
  onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
  options={options}
  labelKey='value'
/>
```

Is there a way to nest the extra options into a new dropdown with the current dropdown menu? I.e.Get extraOptions to show when value 'three' is selected within the dropdown.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want all the options including the extra ones to be available in dropdown? do you want the extra options to become available only after choosing the options? or do you want the options to be sort of grouped within the selection?

Comment: Yes I want the extraOptions to show when value 'three' is selected within the dropdown.